# how to install specific qt modules in linux so i can compile my code with that modules only

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4, qt5

I want to download and install only concurrent and core modules of  qt5 not everything else
    it provides then how to install it in Linux.

**Note:** I don't want to download everything form INTERNET but these two modules,
and install in Linux so I can compile my code with these two modules.

I already tried a lot searching but couldn't find anything.

So what could be done.

Comment: or am i looking for some which isn't possible ??

Comment: On what Linux distributions? Why do you want to do that? I guess it might not be possible.... Why don't you just limit the set of Qt libraries to be installed on the target system??? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Actually my requirement is up to these two modules only.

Comment: You will have to build Qt from source on your target platform. Then grab the two modules you want instead of installing the whole package.

Comment: You may want to describe *why* you want to do this, as the vast majority of Linux distros come with all the modules anyway, making this a pointless exercise.

Comment: i use ubuntu 14.04 and i guess it doesn't include qt5 modules by default?? or it includes??